# How to change the objectGUID

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am restoring the deleted ad object. while restoring it i want provide the same guid for the object. if the object is in tombstone then i can get the same guid while creating it. But if the deleted object is not available in the tombstone then i've to create a new object with same attributes. so i want to restore the guid of the newly created object. Is it possible to assign GUID?

Comment: I think Guid cannot be setted manually

Answer (score 4):

The *objectGUID* attribute is a system attribute also called *operational attribute* in LDAP vocabulary. This means that it's setup by the Directory itself during object creation and that it can't be modified via LDAP.

In other directories it's possible to modify it directly in the database, but according to me, in Active-Directory, it's not officialy documented by Microsoft.

This attribute is the only one which allow to distinghish an object in the Directory.